# Hibernate delete all rows and start indexing from 1

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql

I want to update my database every night for new values. Simply speaking 'start over' by deleting all rows and store new data.

So far I'm doing it using these two queries:

```
public void deleteProduct() {
        Transaction transaction = null;
        try (Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession()) {
            transaction = session.beginTransaction();
            session.createQuery("DELETE FROM Product").executeUpdate();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (transaction != null) {
                transaction.rollback();
            }
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

And

```
public void saveProduct(Product student) {
        Transaction transaction = null;
        try (Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession()) {
            transaction = session.beginTransaction();
            // save the student object
            session.save(student);
            transaction.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (transaction != null) {
                transaction.rollback();
            }
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

For each element.

The problem I'm dealing with is that after deletion and insertion of new values. 
The indexes of my records are started not from zero but from the number of the last row before deletion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could delete the tables, and rebuild them with an equally simple sql statement. Or, you could ignore your key value, so long as it's unique and doing it's job. Make your own column as a counter and let the key be the key. That's several alternatives right there. But I would rebuild the table if you really are liking that key to start over at 1 again.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Have a nice day and stay healthy!

Comment: You're welcome. I've had times where I wanted to see that primary key remain uniform when things are removed when auto increment columns are present. I honestly learned over time to stop looking at it; it was irrelevant to operations, and was only relevant to my own sense of order as a human. :D

Comment: You could place the syntax of your create table statements into a resource file so that it isn't hardcoded into the app. Each night, you drop the tables in a routine, and read in the create table statements from your resource file. You then will have external control, and can change easily your table structure just by altering the resource file. Or, hardcode your create table statement. Good luck.